# What is the name of the random distribution whose samples have a scale that is uniformly random scale within a given range?

Tags: probability-distributions

In Machine Learning, during hyperparameter tuning, if you don't have a clue about the scale of the hyperparameter that you are trying to tune, it is common practice to perform grid search with roughly geometrically increasing values, for example: `[0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0, 10.0, 30.0, 100.0]`.

Using NumPy, I can sample 1,000 numbers from such a distribution like so:

```
x = np.rand(1000) * 10 - 5  # x is uniform random in [-5, 5]
y = np.exp(x)
```

I suppose this distribution is well known. If so, what is its name? I would like to find it in the [list of distribution functions in scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/stats.html).

**Edit**

I'm not very familiar with the mathematical notations, but I guess it might look something like this:

I'm looking for the name of the random distribution $ Y = \exp(X) $

with $X \sim\ \mathcal{U}(-5, 5)$

where $\mathcal{U}$ represents the uniform distribution,

Thanks!

Comment: For future questions, if there is no coding, use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical symbols.

Comment: @Arbuja Good point, I edited the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the [reciprocal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_distribution).

Let $U\sim \mathcal{U}(a,b)$ and $X=\exp(U)$. Then, the CDF is given by:
$$
F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=P(U\leq \ln(x))=\frac{\ln(x) - a}{b-a}
$$
using the CDF of $U$.
Then, the PDF is:
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\ln(x) - a}{b-a}
= \frac{1}{(b-a)x}
$$
where $e^a \leq x \leq e^b$.

It's [conveniently implemented in scipy :)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.reciprocal.html#scipy.stats.reciprocal). See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234544/from-uniform-distribution-to-exponential-distribution-and-vice-versa).

Comment: I knew it had to be there somewhere!  Thanks a lot @user3658307.